# Getting image name in an already existing page using session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am using a page where you can submit a photo and send an email for its approval. But it sends email even if I don't add a new image. Is it possible to get the image name using session in C#.

Sorry for the silly question. I am new to ASP.NET.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you share some code and show what you've already tried?

Answer (score 0):

The image name would not be stored in the session unless you explicitly put it there (I don't recommend that).  You should look for the image name in Request.Form or Request.QueryString.  [This article has some good code examples](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1757/File-Upload-with-ASP-NET).